# Android Button not filling full space in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a button, aligned to the bottom of the page. I want it to fill 100% space, from left, right and bottom. Whatever attributes I will choose, there are still very small non covered areas. Can you please help?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="search"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Here is the screenshot, showing not filled areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v18zD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space you see is the shadow around the button in its background drawable. You need to create your own background drawable and it should then completely occupy the width.

Or, you could also just set the background to null.

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: Thank you so much androholic. This is exactly what I needed! Unfortunately I am not yet able to vote your answer up... Will come back here when I have enough rep.

Comment: This is simpler than my solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a file in `drawable` folder like this, say `simple_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- Normal color -->
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- Color - when the view is pressed -->
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now simply set the background as the above created drawable.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/simple_selector"
        android:text="search"

        />
```

The above code can change color in both `normal` and `pressed` states of the button. You can change the colors as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer AxeFox. This works like a charm too :)