# Get rid of gap between image view and button with linear layout

Tags: java, android

There is a gap between my button and an image view when using a linear layout. They are both added programmatically

I have tried changing the bounds of the image but it didn't do anything

The button is added with

```java
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText(title);

button.setTextSize(20);
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
button.setHeight(35);
button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
button.setWidth(screenWidth - 8 * 2);
button.setId(buttons + 1);
button.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
button.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, expand, null);
```

Then in the listener, I add the image view to the linear layout which works.
Linear layout

```java
Drawable test;
test = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.typicalscheme);
test.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 400); //Changed this line to varous numbers and removed it too, neither changed the gap
imageView.setImageDrawable(test);
```

I use `linearLayout.addView(imageViews[popTypeButtons]);` which references the image view to add the view.

I expect the image view to be directly beside the button but they are apart. I have done the same thing with a text view which works correctly, just not the image view

Image Code

```java
Drawable test;
test = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.typicalscheme);
test.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 0);
imageView.setImageDrawable(test);
```

It is added to the linear layout later by a button with

```java
linearLayout.addView(imageViews[popTypeButtons]);
//refers to array of image views
```

Comment: is this a vertical or horizontal linear layout?

Comment: Also can you add the imageview code as well

Comment: Maybe the gap is due to the fact that a Button does not fill its allocated space completely, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186506/android-button-not-filling-full-space-in-relativelayout)

Comment: @HayesRoach, it is a vertical layout

Comment: @0X0nosugar, the gap is not there when using a text view, only the image